# javascript reference in a hyperlink?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to include a javascript "call" as part of a single weblink?
I frequent a webpage that the programmer has chosen to use javascript to route visitors to various pages and resources. I am trying to build a "training" reference that uses links instead of verbose descriptions to guide members to a specific destination.
For example, Starting with the URL "http://spacechicken.net/faction/access.asp", a javascript call "javascript:SubmitMain("/faction/main.asp","u~10386")" routes to another page. I'm not really familiar with either, so I'm hoping that there's an easy way to connect the js call directly to the end of the URL so that a single click routes the member directly to the destination page???

Answer (score 1):

No, this would be a massive attack vector if it was a thing.

Imagine this scenario:

- You get a message on Facebook from an old friend who says they're launching their new business and want to give you a free sample (of something so amazing you just can't say no).
- The send you a `bit.ly` link to their new page, which in turn masks the JavaScript in the URL.
- You click the link and a bit of JS is executed stealing some data out of your session.

As a solution:

- Does, after authentication, the webpage you're referring to have some form of `#` IDs floating around that you could link to?
- It's possible that you could wrap the website in your own application that authenticates and reroutes requests automatically, to save the end user needing to do so. You can use APIs such as `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ...)` to fire off a `POST` request and log into the application using the data you've listed here.